# semantic-ui form validation: image url

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Is it possible to validate that an input is an image url?

I tried the following naive approach:

```
validations.img = {
      identifier: 'img',
      rules: [{
        type: 'url',
        prompt: 'not a valid URL'
      },
      {
        type: "contains[.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tiff, .tif]",
        prompt: 'not image'
      }]
    };
```

But it looks like contains is doing an AND operation. Can I make it do an OR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`semantic-ui` allows you to add your on validation rules adding function on `$.fn.form.settings.rules` so for example if you want to check if the `string` contains one of your array elements `[.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tiff, .tif]` you can add a new function for example `containsInArray` as follows:

```
// function to check if the text contains an element from the array
$.fn.form.settings.rules.containsInArray = function(text,csv){
    var array = csv.split(','); // you're separating the string by commas
    var isContains = false; // return value
    // for each element check it usign contains function
    $.each(array,function(index,elem){
        if($.fn.form.settings.rules.contains(text,$.trim(elem))){
            // if condition are meet set the result as true
            // and breaks the loop
            isContains = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    console.log(text + " " + isContains);
    return isContains; 
};
```

Probably the function could be more efficient you can try to improve it, however it works for your case.

Then you have to change the rules, to use `type: "containsInArray[.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tiff, .tif]"` instead of `type: "contains[.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tiff, .tif]"`.

See this working <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjahnvmk/11/)</kbd>